# Change background-color on status bar for cordova applicaton

Tags: react-native, cordova

I have been working on a react.js application which we made into a native app for deployment on cordova. I am working on the android platform side of this application and was wondering does anyone know how to change the background color of the the status bar and the icons so i can make my top nav bar and the status bar looking flush? Any help i would be very grateful.

[image]

As you can see the back is visible when i scroll i want this to be soild white with black icons.

Answer (score 0):

To change the background color for an android application on Cordova is straightforward. All you have to do is go to the `config.xml` file and add the following lines:

```xml
<preference name="StatusBarOverlaysWebView" value="true" />
<preference name="StatusBarBackgroundColor" value="YourOwnColor" />
<preference name="StatusBarStyle" value="lightcontent" />
```